# SELECT on indexed column is slow

Tags: mysql, sql

In a MySQL db I have a table that only has 2 columns, for all intents and purposes: a key hash and a value. Both are `INTEGER` type. The hash column will have a large number of duplicates (worst case expect ~80k dup for each hash, not possible to make unique due to small hash preimage), and the table contains on the order of 100 billion rows.

Right now I have the hash column indexed (`CREATE INDEX idx_hash ON table(hash)`); however lookups are very slow. Something like `SELECT value FROM table WHERE hash=123 LIMIT 50` will take minutes if not hours, while a similar select on a similar sized table on a primary key column will finish in a jiffy on the same machine.

So my question is how do I optimize for lookup in this case? Is sub-linear time SELECT possible on index columns? This table will be mostly read-only, rebuilding it is possible but will take a long time, so I'd like to gather some information and do it correctly.

`EXPLAIN` says:

```
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table          | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows      | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | partial_lookup | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 100401571 |    10.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+----------+-------------+
```

`ANALYZE`:

```
+--------------------+---------+----------+----------+
| Table              | Op      | Msg_type | Msg_text |
+--------------------+---------+----------+----------+
| partial_lookup     | analyze | status   | OK       |
+--------------------+---------+----------+----------+
1 row in set (1.47 sec)
```

Comment: When you have so many duplicates, the cardinality of the index may not be high enough to make it seem useful. What does `EXPLAIN` say?

Comment: Hi @Barmar, kinda pain to format it here, pastebin link to `EXPLAIN`: https://pastebin.com/raw/vd7SmMU9 (row count is not the final number because I did not let it populate fully). Is the slowness what happens when index contains too many duplicates?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for formatting help.

Comment: Not sure why `EXPLAIN` says there's no possible keys. BTW, you have 100 million rows, not 100 billion.

Comment: MySQL might not be the best DBMS for such a huge database.

Comment: I'd suggest running `ANALYZE TABLE partial_lookup;` in case the optimizer hasn't yet figured out there's an index there. Also is this MySQL 8.0 with its new data dictionary? I reported a [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86170) about 8.0 failing to sample index statistics, so I had to set `set information_schema_stats_expiry=0;`

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for helping out. 100m is only part of the data, I figured to give it a test before spending days to filling in the rest. Would you suggest some other database for this kind of operation? (Sorry I'm very new to databases in general)

Comment: For such enormous data, you might need to spend the money for something like Oracle.

Comment: Hi @BillKarwin yep this is 8.0. I did an `ANALYZE` and it did seem to make it a bit faster (?), however increasing the `LIMIT` number still (proportionally) increase the query time, which makes me think it's still doing an O(n) scan on the whole table D:

Comment: Can you run the EXPLAIN after you did ANALYZE TABLE? Does it now list the index `idx_hash` under `possible_keys`, and does it list that index under `keys`?